# Keyboard pushes text field inside modal popUp to the top

Tags: css, ionic-framework

In my app as soon as the popup(modal) apear with the component (add) inside him, the component is an input,when i want to write something the keyboard push my component and my modal to the top.

I want it to be fixed even if the keyboard is here.

This is the modal.html

```
<ion-content class="card"  overflow-scroll="false"padding>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-buttons start>
    <button style="background-color: #F8F8F8">
       <ion-icon name="close"style="font-size: 25px;
       background-color: #F8F8F8"   (click)="dismiss()"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>

  </ion-navbar>

  <add></add>
  <button ion-button color="red" >
  </button>
</ion-content>
```

the css of the model.css

```
.card {
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height:55%;
  top: 10%;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  left: 5%; 
  right: 5%; 
  bottom: 5%;
  background-color: red;

}
```

The component.html

```
<div class="add-content">
  <div>
    <ion-item class="code">
      <ion-input type="text" maxlength="4"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <span class="dash">-</span>
    <ion-item class="code">
      <ion-inputtype="text" maxlength="4"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </div>
  </div>
```

component.css

```
add .code {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 37%;
}

add button {
 margin: 5%
}

add input {
  letter-spacing: 4.8px;
  text-align:center
}
```

Comment: Can you create stackblitz demo example?

Comment: @Yerkon in the web app it's, okey, but when it's on android the keyboard is pushing the component to the top of the modal

Comment: If you create stackblitz, I can run it in virtual device to reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue while keyboard open it will move my screen little bit up

for this you need to disable scroll while keyboard open.

**try to add this code in your component constructor :**

```
constructor(
 public keyboard: Keyboard,
 platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      this.keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    });

}
```

I solve my problem by above code please try and let me know is it working for you or not.

Comment: Sorry not working, i think i need to do something in the css.

Comment: This issue is related to keyboard so i dont think so css patch will work on this as default css will apply while keyboard present on screen.